# Html entities to Html tags

Tags: html, encoding, web, wysiwyg, html-entities

I'm using `wysiwyg` text editor named "`niceEdit`".
when I want to present the content extracted from the database the html tags are in the form of [html entities](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp). for example: `&lt;`

so, the result (in the webpage) might be something like:

```
<b>hello world</b>
```

instead of:

> **hello world**

what is the easy/elegant way to convert it?

P.S.
I use JAVA (Play! framework) in the backend.

Comment: What is your server-side language? Do you use JS framework?

Comment: if you use PHP - [**html_entity_decode**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)

Comment: I use play! framework (java web-framework)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do it: http://jsfiddle.net/QSJxW/

In a nutshell you create a form that does nothing and has no submit button. Add a textarea
to your form and put all of your code between `<textarea>` and `</textarea>`. You can use
CSS to style your textarea so that it doesn't LOOK like a text area.

I have 2 examples in my jsFiddle. One unstyled and one styled. If you add overflow:hidden
to the textarea CSS, it turns off the scrolling.

Hope this helps!

Cynthia

Comment: this is a creative idea, but is it the best practice?

Comment: I don't know that there *is* a best practice for what you want to do. All I know is that it is clean code and that it works. The alternative is to use ASCII to generate the left and right brackets, but that isn't an effecient way to do it - especially if we're talking several lines of code. That many &lt; and &gt; - it's too easy to accidentally omit an & or a ; and then your code is fubar'd.